# XML file to UTF-8 no result

Tags: xml, utf-8

Why isn't the following code doing converting to UTF-8

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(FileName);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent=true };

using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationFile))
{
  using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, settings))
  {
    //  writer.WriteStartDocument();

    doc.Save(writer);
  }
}
```

My Aim is to convert a given xml file to utf-8, but the result of the above code is the file come's out Ansi. Tried this a hundred times with no results.

Comment: What language is this? (I'd guess C#). How do you verify that the file "comes out Ansi"? How did you check that?

Comment: How do you know that it's ANSI? Are you expecting a BOM?

Comment: What is the content of your file?  ANSI characters are represented in the same manner in UTF-8.  You'll only see high-byte chars if UTF-8 is needed to represent a non-ANSI character.

Comment: I can check through notepad++ and notepad. It shows me ansi.

Comment: Have you verified this through any other programs?  http://codeftw.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-find-character-encoding-of-text.html has a good suggestion of simply opening the file in FireFox and letting it tell you what the encoding is...